# Capture User Select From photoLibrary UIImagePicker In SWIFTUI View

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I am new to SWIFT UI, and trying to allow a user to select a photo from their local library in a SWIFT UI view. I am stuck on actually capturing the user action.

This is my attempt to create the picker:

```
final class ChooseImageView: NSObject, UIViewControllerRepresentable, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate  {
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ChooseImageView>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let libraryPicker = UIImagePickerController()
        libraryPicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        libraryPicker.delegate = self
        
        return libraryPicker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController,
                                context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ChooseImageView>) {
        
    }
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        
        // I don't see this ever
        print("I got a change")
    }
    
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I am trying to embed it into a view that looks something like this:

```
struct PhotoPage: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            ChooseImageView()
        }
    }

}
```

Does anybody know how I can get that print statement to execute?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I ran your code and I could see the print statement in my console.

[image]

Comment: Interesting, did you add anything to info.plist? Maybe that's where I'm having a problem?

Comment: It was a fresh project and I didn't add anything to the info.plist

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I left my variable declarations in the view assuming they couldn't be the problem. It turns out the line '@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode' was the source of my problems.

Comment: Glad it helped :)